# How to delete Unnamed index row and replace 0th row as index row in python for data analysis

Tags: python, indexing, row

[This image showing rows which need to be deleted I have tried deleting it with drop() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzReZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0,:]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.